# I am a 26-year-old who hasn’t or haven’t?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

1. I’m a 26 year old guy who hasn’t watched X...
2. I’m a 26 year old guy who haven’t watched X...
   Which one would be accurate?

Comment: Can you see the difference between "I'm a 26-year old who **hasn't** watched X" and "I'm 26 and **haven't** watched X"? Hint: it has to do with the person (1st, 2nd, 3rd)  that verb must take to match the subject of the clause. Does that help or hurt?

Comment: I'm afraid that would be confusing @user105719. Finding the subject is a difficult task for a learner. Also, you mention the category of person (1st, 2nd, 3rd),which is only relevant in case of pronoun. So the only pronoun here is "I". So does that mean the correct answer is neither "haven't" nor "hasn't", but "am not"?

Comment: @user178049 Do you really think finding the subject of a clause is too difficult for a learner? It's hard for me to judge since I'm a native speaker, but without knowing the subject, the right form of the predicate will be impossible to discern. *I have/you have/he has* (1st, 2nd, 3rd). Notice that *I* is singular, but the verb form wouldn't be *hasn't*. The key here is that *who*, although it refers to a first person pronoun, takes a third person verb.

Comment: There's got to be similar questions already asked on ELL with answers that could be helpful to OP. Strangely I can't find any and thus can't vote duplicate on this. @user105719 I think you should flesh out your explanation as an answer.

Comment: @user105719 Problem with learners is that they do not realize that a sentence may have two or more subjects. For example, in this case, the subject in the superordinate clause is "I" and the subject in the subordinate clause is "who", which is linked to the NP "25-year-old a guy". Also, you are talking about 1st and 2nd person pronouns and that is not relevant since the NP "25-year-old a guy" is not a personal pronoun. It is actually matter of plurality here, not number of person. The category of number would only be relevant if the actual subject was "I".

Comment: @user178049 I'm gonna try one more time to explain and then leave the field. Otherwise, I find myself turning into that internet guy who has to have the last word, and I don't like that guy. The deciding factor between the present forms of verbs is person, although this happens only in the singular. If number were the factor, then singular first person and singular third person, having the same number, should have the same form for their verbs, but they don't. It's *I **have*** but  *he **has***.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subject-verb-agreement](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6759/subject-verb-agreement)

Answer (score 1):

The relative pronoun "who" is linked to the noun phrase "a 26-year-old guy", which is singular. So the correct verb to use is "hasn't".

Answer (score 1):

## Who has?  I have.

## Who has it?   I have it.

Don’t be confused by the contractions “hasn’t” and “haven’t.”

Here, ￼**who** works just like she, he, or it. It’s a **third** person singular *relative pronoun*. There are no plural subjects in your sentence.

> ✔️**Correct:**
>
> I have, you have.
>
> She has, he has, it has, **who has.**

So to answer your question:

> ✔️ **Correct:**
>
> I am a guy **who has** a shirt.
>
> I am a guy **who has** many shirts.
>
> I am a guy **who wears** many hats.
>
> I am not a guy **who has** been arrested.
>
> I am a knight **who has** not been defeated.

### Who can be plural.

Who is plural when it refers to more than one person.  Then it takes “who have”, like “they have”.

> ✔️ **Correct:**
>
> The teachers **who have** quit are Alice, Bob and Carl.
>
> The only teacher **who has** been fired is David.