# Use of the singular/plural in "there is a multitude"

Tags: singular-vs-plural, collective-nouns

I understand that "multitude" expresses a collective noun. While writing the sentence:

> There **is** a multitude of articles and blog posts written on the topic,

the Google doc spellcheck flagged that I should instead use "there are a multitude" which seems wrong to me, given the word "multitude" is singular. However, I am not a native English speaker and I know I've stumbled onto counterintuitive things in the past about this topic (e.g. "the police are"), so I'm asking for the wisdom of the crowd.

Comment: You are correct. However, style guides vary, and native English speakers tend to use plural verbs after collective nouns as often as singular verbs, sometimes influenced by context. (100 dollars is a lot of money; 100 dollars are lying on the floor) The only rule is to be consistent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the form of a verb be determined by the meaning of the subject instead of its grammatical number?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6688/can-the-form-of-a-verb-be-determined-by-the-meaning-of-the-subject-instead-of-it)  As with other nouns that are grammatically singular, but have plural meanings, there is variation:  "The team is" and "The team are" both can be correct.  There is also dialect variation.  US English prefers "multitude is" UK prefers "multitude are", but there is variation on both sides of the atlantic.

Comment: Yes thanks @JamesK - didn't find that question when searching for something similar.